# How to learn JQuery coming from a Drupal background but with little to no knowledge of Javascript?

Tags: 7, javascript

So here I am in 2012 and although I've been making websites in my spare time for several years, I've managed to get the results I needed by using Drupal and simply cutting and pasting Javascript snippets, etc. when necessary.

Recently, I've got into development more seriously and I have some time to study the right way to do things so I've decided that I'd like to learn jQuery.  Basically, I'd like to make my sites a little more exciting and interactive; in the past, the sites I have built have been praised/criticized as "highly informative but very plain."

That said, I don't know much about Javascript to begin with.  Where should I start?  If it matters all my projects going forward will be in Drupal 7.

I was looking forward to the JQuery and Drupal videos on [drupalize.me](http://drupalize.me), but unfortunately I live in Japan and have a slow Internet connection which makes it almost impossible to stream the videos.

Comment: Japan? Slow internet connection? Wow, that's unusual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, you should try and pick up some knowledge of JavaScript (JS).

A good way to learn jQuery, which is a library of JavaScript, when you know the basis of JS is [30 Days to Learn jQuery](http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/). I've done this course myself and they give a lot of tips and best practices! Also [Learning jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/) has some good tips.

To start off with JavaScript itself, take a peek at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)!

Answer (score 1):

Understanding basics of Javascript is very important to effectively use and extend jQuery. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M